# Turn off whole word search on Atom

Tags: atom-editor

I'm trying to search within a word on Atom and can't work out how to do it! I searched online and it seems the whole word feature was added recently - is there a way of turning it off?

I don't know regex but if there's some kind of solution using that that would be fine!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the find panel, there are a few icons on the right side. They are as follows (at least, as of today in v1.16), from left to right:

- Regex (regular expression matching)
- Case sensitive search
- Search only within current selection
- Match whole words

You can click any of them to toggle their state on/off.